# How would I recreate this type of chart in R? (Plotting Regression / Treatment Effects)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been trying to recreate a similar chart to this one (see image below) that was originally created in Stata.

[image: Original Chart in Stata]

Here's what I've tried so far in R:

```
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 3, nrow = 10))
row.names(df2) <- c("FB", "IG", "Network TV News", "Local TV News", "Cable News", "Print Newspapers", "Radio", "Friends and Family", "Online News", "YouTube")
df2$X1 <- runif(10, min = -2, max = -1.5)
df2$X2 <- runif(10, min = -1.5, max = 0.5)
df2$X3 <- runif(10, min = 0.5, max = 2)

df2_names <- factor(row.names(df2), levels = c("YouTube", "Online News", "Friends and Family", "Radio", "Print Newspapers", "Cable News", "Local TV News", "Network TV News", "IG", "FB"))

#Output Figure

base <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=df2_names, y=X2))
               
fig2 <- base + geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = X1, ymax = X3, y=X2)) +
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), plot.margin = margin(2, 2, 2, 2, "cm")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "red", size=1)
```

[image: Attempted Chart in R]

What I'm struggling with is reducing the space in between the y-axis labels, and creating breakpoints. Is geom_pointrange in ggplot2 the right way to go, or are there alternatives that I should check out?

Comment: You can adjust the y spacing just by saving the plot with a smaller height.

Comment: Use scale_x_continuous for x axis breaks and limits. Use scale_y_manual if you need to change breaks to the y axis. Space between breaks is going to depend on how many breaks there are and how big the plot is.

Answer (score 1):

A relatively easy way to get apparent groupings is to use sneaky facets - that is, facets that don't look like facets. This also gives full control over grouping.

```r
groups <- rev(c("Youtube", "Online News", "Friends and Family", "Radio", "Print Newspapers",
            rep("TV", 3), "Social Media", "Social Media"))
df2$Category <- factor(groups, levels = unique(groups))

base <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=df2_names, y=X2))
               
base + geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = X1, ymax = X3, y=X2)) +
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "red", size=1) + 
  facet_grid(Category~., scales = "free_y") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "points"),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = margin(2, 2, 2, 2, "cm"),
        panel.background  = element_rect(linetype = 2, colour = "gray75", fill = NA),
        axis.line.y.right = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

[image]

An alternative is to insert blank factor levels where you want breaks:

```r
df2 <- rbind(df2, `colnames<-`(matrix(NA, ncol = 3, nrow = 2), c("X1", "X2", "X3")))
rownames(df2)[11:12] <- c(" ", "  ")
df2_names <- factor(row.names(df2), 
                    levels = c("YouTube", "Online News", "Friends and Family", "Radio", " ",
                               "Cable News", "Local TV News", "Network TV News", "  ", "IG", "FB"))


base <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=df2_names, y=X2))
               
base + geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = X1, ymax = X3, y=X2)) +
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "red", size=1) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = " ", linetype = 2, color = "gray75") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = "  ", linetype = 2, color = "gray75") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Also adding `scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0.6,0.6))` after `coord_flip()` reduce the space but after that I am unable to avoid that extra space created!